# Sum and multiply if not blank

Tags: excel

I have 10 columns where some of the columns may or may not contain data.
I need to sum the product of 2 and 2 columns IF they have data. Simplest way:

=(A1*B1)+(C1*D1)...

This will of course return an error (#value) if some of the columns are empty. Note that the pairs are either both blank or both with data.

Is it best to check with ISNUMBER:

=IF(ISNUMBER(A1*B1);0)+(IF(ISNUMBER(C1*D1);0).. ?

Comment: Perhaps use `SUMPRODUCT`. But... "This will of course return an error (#value) if some of the columns are empty." - then most likely the column is not *empty*. The result of multiplying empty cells is `0`, not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, Excel treats blanks as zeros.  Consider:

```
=(A1*B1)+(C1*D1)+(E1*F1)
```

[image]

If either element of a pair *(or both elements)* are blank, the product is zero and they do not contribute to the sum.